# How to send a file stored in contentversion to an external api

Tags: contentversion

My question is specifically related to getting a file stored in contentversion and converting it to string.

I want to send this to an external service to parse file and return an xml which i am not having a problem.

I did a quick code on Execute Anonymous in Developer console and i get an error

> System.StringException: BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string

```
 ContentVersion  cv = [SELECT versionData,PathOnClient FROM ContentVersion
         WHERE id='068900000031bg7AAA' LIMIT 1];
bighelpdesk.CVParseAPISoap ap = new bighelpdesk.CVParseAPISoap();
String b  = cv.versiondata.tostring(); // **Errors out at this line**
String xmlString = ap.parseResume(b,cv.PathOnClient,'xxxxx-0d80-e611-xxx-xxxxxxxx','xxxxxx');
System.debug('xmlString ' + xmlString);
```

The use case is to send a resume for parsing and based on the results create a salesforce record.

Comment: Did you try `EncodingUtil.base64Encode`?

Comment: yes, it still throws the same error